# How can i get top row in partition?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

| Sport | Athlete | Year | Medal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hockey | COWLEY, Gillian Margaret | 1980 | Gold |
| hockey | DAVIES, Patricia Joan | 1980 | Gold |
| rowing | REIC, Josip | 1980 | Bronze |
| Aquatics | COVENTRY, Kirsty | 2004 | Silver |
| Boxing | SKARO, Damir | 1988 | Bronze |
| Boxing | KACAR, Slobodan | 1980 | Gold |

This is what my table is looks like. I want to partition by sport and get first row.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Sport ORDER BY Athlete ) as rn, Athlete, Event
FROM `table`
WHERE rn = 1
```

But i can't use Where condition and getting this error;

> Column rn contains an analytic function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [1:147]

Have any alternative solution?

Comment: Your query has no `GROUP BY`. so that is an unexpected error.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Sport ORDER BY Athlete ) as rn, Athlete, Event 
      FROM `table`
     ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

A more colloquial way to do this in BQ uses aggregation, though:

```
select array_agg(t order by athlete asc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from `table` t
group by sport;
```

Comment: Thanks, subquery is work. But get the same error in the other solution, i can't group by sport.

Comment: @asiyenuryilmaz . . . This works in #standardSQL.  Might you be using legacy SQL by any chance?